# <Image> tag working differently in iOS and Android for a React app

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, image, react-native

[Android Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAnSK.png)

[iOS Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9raak.png)

```
<View style={styles.spaceP}>
        <Collapse>
            <CollapseHeader>
                <Separator bordered style={styles.dropHeader}>
                    <Text style={styles.dropHeaderText}>Airports of Quito and Guayaquil</Text>
                </Separator>
            </CollapseHeader>
            <CollapseBody>
                <ListItem >
                    <Text style={styles.dropBodyText}>In the airports of Quito and Guayaquil prior to the check-in with your airline you must:{"\n"}{"\n"}
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Step 1:</Text> Register with the Galapagos Government Council Office to obtain your Transit Control Card (TCT) cost of the TCT is $20.00{"\n"}{"\n"}
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} onPress={ ()=> Linking.openURL('https://siiws.gobiernogalapagos.gob.ec/siicgg_web/') } >Fill out the Previous Registration Form for the TCT here </Text>{"\n"}{"\n"}
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} onPress={ ()=> Linking.openURL('https://siiws.gobiernogalapagos.gob.ec/siicgg_web/') } >Fill out the New Registration Form for the TCT here </Text>{"\n"}{"\n"}
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Step 2:</Text> Check your baggage in the Galapagos ABG Biosecurity Control and Regulation Agency{"\n"}{"\n"}
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Step 3:</Text>At Baltra and San Cristobal airports: As an entrance tax to the protected areas of Galapagos, an entrance tax will be charged, the prices of which are detailed below:{"\n"}{"\n"}
                    <Image
                        source={require('../../app/assets/images/image_tct.jpg')}
                        style={{
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        height: 350,
                        width: 300*rem
                        
                        }}
                        resizeMode="stretch"
                        />    
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Step 4:</Text>An ABG inspector from the Agency for the Regulation and Control of Biosecurity for Galapagos will check your suitcase to make sure that no organic products that may bring organisms that threaten the Galapagos ecosystems are entering.</Text>
                    
                </ListItem>
            </CollapseBody>
        </Collapse>
```

The Image Tag aligns properly on an iPhone, but on android it looks really messy as it drools over the text. How do I fix the Android version??

Answer (score 0):

`resizeMode="stretch"` might conflict with `width` and `height` properties.

You can use concrete values for image

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
```

or live them auto